# How to send a JFace Dialog to the background or minimize it?

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, swt, jface

I am working with a wizard dialog.

It should be possible for the user to click to background and be able to interact with it (in my case that's the eclipse editor since I am writing a Plug-In).

However, the background is always locked, not focusable. Is there a way to disable this property and access the background without closing the wizard dialog entirely? After having done some stuff in the editor it should be possible to return to the wizard and finish the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the dialog 'modeless' so that it does not block the application (like the Find/Replace dialog in Eclipse).

Call

```
setShellStyle(getShellStyle() ^ SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.MODELESS);

setBlockOnOpen(false);
```

in the constructor for the `Dialog` to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to do this outside of the constructor? I am using a refactoring wizard which creates the dialog for me, therefore I have no access to its construction.

Comment: You can't change the Shell style once it has been created.

Comment: While it is true that the shell style cannot be changed once the shell is created, JFace dialogs create the shell only in `Window#createShell()`. This method is called from `Window#open()` or `create()` (depending on how you open the dialog). Hence, you can change the shell style as long as `open()` hasn't been called.

Comment: I am using a `RefactoringWizardOpenOperation` which creates and opens the dialog without me being able to interact with it.

Comment: In which case you can't change the dialog. Also a dialog which was not designed to be modeless might run in to problems if it was run as modeless.